# Dummy Package in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

Could someone help ?

I am using the dummy package in R (function dummy) to convert a categorical variable(10 categories) into dummy variables because some of the algorithms I am using (adaboost and rotation forest), don't handle categorical variables well.

After using the package I get 10 dummy variables but they are factors. I expected them to be numeric with 1s and 0s.

Should I convert them to numeric ? or use them as factors.

thanks a lot !!!!
all the best
Pedro

Comment: What function of the package are you using? if it's function `dummy` see  argument `int` in the help page.

Comment: If you should convert them depends on: a) the technically required input of the functions you plan to use (adaboost and rotation forest) b) some functions handle factors and numeric values differntly. so you have to make sure you're not creating problems by casting factors to numeric values.

Comment: thank you. I have used the function dummy. Already added that information to the question.

Comment: Thank you Rui, I saw that. But which option should I chose ? does it depend on what those algorithms ask for ?

Comment: Yes it does. If you're using function `adaboost` from package `fastAdaboost` then the response should be a `factor`.

Answer (score 0):

After performing one hot encoding  there is no difference  keeping them as factor or numeric . Its better not to perform one hot encoding for Tree based models.It will decrease performance.[Here is an article describing effect of one hotted variables.](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/).It better to pass the categorical variables by converting them into factors